# LDAP - Cannot Add OrganizationalUnit

Tags: openldap

I am very new to LDAP and adding to my insanity.

I used the following code to create a database for a domain. Each domain will have its own database incase it is no longer valid etc.

```
version: 1

dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /data/ldap/example.intra
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=intra" write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=intra" write by * read
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbConfig: {0}set_cachesize 0 2097152 0
olcDbConfig: {1}set_lk_max_objects 1500
olcDbConfig: {2}set_lk_max_locks 1500
olcDbConfig: {3}set_lk_max_lockers 1500
olcDbIndex: objectClass                 eq
olcDbIndex: sn                          pres,sub,eq
olcDbIndex: uid                         pres,sub,eq
olcDbIndex: displayName                 pres,sub,eq
olcDbIndex: cn                          pres,sub,eq
olcDbIndex: default                     sub
olcDbIndex: uidNumber                   eq
olcDbIndex: gidNumber                   eq
olcDbIndex: mail,givenName          eq,subinitial
olcDbIndex: dc                      eq
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=intra
olcRootPW: {SSHA}fJnMxL3dHhxKhDkFyK/MwKeRB4iY/NQ0
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=intra
```

When I try and create an organizationalUnit with the following code it refuses:

```
version: 1

dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb, cn=admin, ou=People, dc=example,dc=intra
changetype: modify
add: objectClass
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People
description: All People and Human Like Entities in the example.intra Organisation
```

Please could some really nice person show me what I need to write to get the update and if possible some content into this database?

I am using the following command line to do the work:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f filename.ldif
```

This is the response that I get:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
ldapadd: wrong attributeType at line 16, entry "olcDatabase={1}hdb, cn=admin, ou=People, dc=example,dc=intra"
```

Thanks and kind regards,

jB

Comment: 'It refuses' is not a problem description. There was an error message. It told you why. What did you conclude from that?

Comment: Yup you are correct, slap me harder next time... grin
    
    SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
    SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
    SASL SSF: 0
    ldapadd: wrong attributeType at line 16, entry "olcDatabase={1}hdb, cn=admin, ou=People, dc=molino,dc=intra"

Comment: Your second olcDatabase line has an invalid DN. Databases are defined in the 'cn=config' database only.